# Which server is used by SpringMain class internally for deployment

Tags: spring

Just curious...which server is used by SprinMain class internally to deploy the beans/springContext when running a Spring core application?

Comment: I think only Spring Boot comes with a preconfigured Http server do you mean what comes with Spring Boot by default?

Comment: What is `SpringMain` class? Where does it come from?

Comment: SpringMain is used to deploy standalone spring core applications